# Motivation for proof of local lemma/construction version

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, algorithms

I am interested in finding intuition to the bounds and proof of the asymmetric local lemma.

I think the $k$-SAT is fairly intuitive, but I would like to understand the general version.

One good candidate is the Moser–Tardos algorithm.  See [Moser and Tardos - A constructive proof of the general Lovász Local Lemma](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.0544).

The questions I would love answered are:

1. The expectation of a random geometric $p$ variable is $\frac{1}{1-p}$, which is a term that appears in the asymmetric local lemma. We could hope to use it intuitively together with the algorithmic version as some 'feedback' bound on the nodes, but I'm not sure how to formalize this.
2. In the paper, the analysis seems very lax, which had me surprised it worked. I am talking about the most basic version (not distributed). For example — the witness tree allows you to break ties arbitrarily over depth, so you don't need to remember if $v$ affected more than one variable (you'd expect the whole point to be that a vertex can affect many at once). This is connected to the fact that we bound the number of times we had to resample an event by the witness trees rooted in it, which yet again seems a very lax bound (especially connected with the above comment). I would expect we'd need a gentler data structure, and add to a coming vertex everyone he might have changed and count those properly. Do note that the local lemma is pretty much tight.

Thus I would both like to hear intuition/motivation, and clarification on how this analysis manages to be tight.

Comment: Wait, isn't the expectation of $Geo(p)$ equal to $\frac{1}{p}$ not $\frac{1}{1-p}$?

Comment: @DavidWhite you're right and that's what I had in mind- we should count how many tries we do until it fails, so for $p$ close to 1 we need a lot of tries.